# Преобразовать текст файла в массив слов в Scala

Tags: intellij-idea, scala

Как сделать так, чтобы текст из файла *hello.txt* преобразовался в массив (каждое слово - отдельный элемент массива, желательно не учитывать знаки препинания)?

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("hello.txt")
    val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()

  }
}
```

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-split-string-example/

Answer (score 0):

Уже нашла:
val arr: Array[String] = lines.split(" ")